# Converting txt to json in python

Tags: python, json, cookies, text

i have an question about json and text files in python.

I have an .txt file with cookies, i have about 11 of them but i will show only 2.
I need to convert them to .json file so i could put them in request headers of an post request.

Here are the cookies in .txt

```
Set-Cookie3: X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-Mail="\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6AZInfMKt5IWY2iftwASOV2SUGxMMn0ofLN6m6Tl5DsSBDGXPI2Uhfb7IkYx4GWgET2U5FJdBpxnvF1wGPEV2zKGC7UpT2CoDkBSZAGtIHzkmI6zjqXxGS/ObRGVSX4BuUaP6A2Tgt9CKVHzVZG8O+hA8dDxdCy513OkmNYLNRT8a5M7VnDGyqg==\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0
Set-Cookie4: X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-News="\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6ARKs9FWrQDcrZGUYbHPO2e7Jux6aRGWLAZt4vjHFRLgqERXDD51hgI8ADM/A3SViCTgpnEfThOKn+rJ4rXRlkyQqq3ZPRdlieQI6g/FYs8RBm5Y0fCcFk5RAHq2VQIibURXAttOjyvVo3JHNuJ38zOmGaytYnSujeI6qFNrtep0YV7Ptq6lKcg==\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0
```

and i want them to look like this

```
{
'Set-Cookie3': 'X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-Mail="\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6AZInfMKt5IWY2iftwASOV2SUGxMMn0ofLN6m6Tl5DsSBDGXPI2Uhfb7IkYx4GWgET2U5FJdBpxnvF1wGPEV2zKGC7UpT2CoDkBSZAGtIHzkmI6zjqXxGS/ObRGVSX4BuUaP6A2Tgt9CKVHzVZG8O+hA8dDxdCy513OkmNYLNRT8a5M7VnDGyqg==\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0',
'Set-Cookie4': 'X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-News="\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6ARKs9FWrQDcrZGUYbHPO2e7Jux6aRGWLAZt4vjHFRLgqERXDD51hgI8ADM/A3SViCTgpnEfThOKn+rJ4rXRlkyQqq3ZPRdlieQI6g/FYs8RBm5Y0fCcFk5RAHq2VQIibURXAttOjyvVo3JHNuJ38zOmGaytYnSujeI6qFNrtep0YV7Ptq6lKcg==\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0'
}
```

the brackets dont have to look like that, they can look like this for example. This will be better, also very important is the comma

```
{'cookie': 'value', 'cookie': 'value'}
```

i tried many solutions but many of them didnt work, for ex. thought each cookie is an different group so they have different brackets, or just quoting the colon.
Any help will be appriciated:))
Thank you!

Comment: Generally: create an empty dict `d = {}`, loop through all lines in the file, for each line split at the first `: `, then do `d[first_part] = second_part`. But that won't work if you have `Set-Cookie3` twice as the key.

Comment: Use the @luk2302 solution. Just keep in mind that dict keys are unique, if all the keys are the same you can simply store the values in a list.

Comment: The two cookies having the same name makes your desired output not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```py
with open("cookies.txt", "r") as f:  # don't forget to change the filename
    txt = f.readlines()
d = {line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[0]: line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[1].lstrip() for line in txt}
```

Output:

```
>>> print(d)
{'Set-Cookie3': 'X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-Mail="\\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6AZInfMKt5IWY2iftwASOV2SUGxMMn0ofLN6m6Tl5DsSBDGXPI2Uhfb7IkYx4GWgET2U5FJdBpxnvF1wGPEV2zKGC7UpT2CoDkBSZAGtIHzkmI6zjqXxGS/ObRGVSX4BuUaP6A2Tgt9CKVHzVZG8O+hA8dDxdCy513OkmNYLNRT8a5M7VnDGyqg==\\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0\n', 'Set-Cookie4': 'X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-PCS-News="\\"TGlzdEFwcGw6MTpBcHBsOjE6ARKs9FWrQDcrZGUYbHPO2e7Jux6aRGWLAZt4vjHFRLgqERXDD51hgI8ADM/A3SViCTgpnEfThOKn+rJ4rXRlkyQqq3ZPRdlieQI6g/FYs8RBm5Y0fCcFk5RAHq2VQIibURXAttOjyvVo3JHNuJ38zOmGaytYnSujeI6qFNrtep0YV7Ptq6lKcg==\\""; path="/"; domain=".icloud.com"; path_spec; domain_dot; secure; expires="2022-06-14 13:29:15Z"; HttpOnly=None; version=0'}
```

Just be careful, as others have noted, there can't be identical keys in a `dict`.